# Dropping All Logins Created by other users in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to be able to drop all login in the sql server which is not the ones i created myself.
  I have used the following code and it executed successfully but the logins remains and nothing changed. Really confused and need help.
  My code is

```
DECLARE @LoginName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE DBLOGINS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals
    WHERE name <> N'schooladmin' and name <> N'school1' and name <> N'school2' and type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN'
and sid <> 0x01 and substring(name, 1, 1) <> '#'

OPEN DBLOGINS

FETCH NEXT FROM DBLOGINS INTO @LoginName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP LOGIN [' + @LoginName + ']'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    FETCH NEXT FROM DBLOGINS INTO @LoginName
END

CLOSE DBLOGINS
DEALLOCATE DBLOGINS
```

Please help.

Comment: check your SELECT statement if you are getting the required login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below modified code, probably you are looking for something like this.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)=''

SELECT @sql +='Drop Login [' + name + '];' +char(13)+char(10) 
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE type_desc = 'SQL_Login' -- Double check this value, I found it SQL_User
  and sid <> 0x01 
  and Left(name, 1) <> '#'
  and name NOT IN( N'schooladmin', N'school1', N'school2')

print @sql
--  Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is executed successfully without doping any login because your Query in the cursor is retrieving always no rows !

Use `OR` instead of `AND` into where clause

as following:

```
  WHERE (name <> N'lisabi' OR name <> N'school1' OR name <> N'school2' ) and type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN'
```